# How to calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^{1+a}} \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-integration, branch-cuts

> Find the value of the following integral:
>
> $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^{1+a}} \, dx, $$
>
> where $0 < a < 1$ is a real number.

I can bound the integral using $\ln(1+x) < x$ for $0 < x < M$ and $\ln(1+x) < x^{a/2}$ for $x>M$, which means that the integral exists and may be calculated by hands.

I think I must interpret the integral in the viewpoint of complex analysis, but I could not handle the log function and $x^{1+a}$, because I am not good at stuffs like branch cuts.

I would be happy if you let me know how to tackle this problem.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks for your edits, Shaun

Comment: it should be $$\frac{\pi  \csc (\pi  a)}{a}$$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner That will help the OP to sort out the branch cuts, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

The integral in its current form is not easy to deal with as it has two logarithms, one $\log (1+x)$ and the other $x^{1+a} = e^{(1+a)\log x}$. So removing one of them does help. Taking integration by parts,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x^{a+1}} \, dx
= \underbrace{ \left[ -\frac{1}{a}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x^a} \right]_{0}^{\infty} }_{=0} + \frac{1}{a} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^a(1+x)}. \tag{*} $$

Now this integral can be attacked by some standard techniques. For instance, you can utilize the keyhole contour. For this technique, it would be good to read [*this*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_4_.E2.80.93_branch_cuts) to see how we choose the branch cut of $\log$ and the contour to compute the integral.

So let me leave the rest of computation to you, but I will write a more detailed answer in case you find it hard to apply it to $\text{(*)}$.

(There are solutions that relies on real-analytic methods if you are familiar with some special functions such as the gamma function. But I will skip them too.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Integration by parts always works...